# 5 Digit Code Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

We have a 5 digit code, any place can take 1 2 or 3.

How do I find where the 2 is placed (if placed) knowing this criteria?

> 1) If the 1st digit is not a 3 then the 2nd is.
>
> 2) If the 1st digit is 3 then the 3rd digit is 2.
>
> 3) If 2nd digit is 3 and 4th is 2 then 5th is 1.
>
> 4) If the 3rd digit is not 2 then the 4th is 2.
>
> 5) If 3rd digit is not 2 then the 5th digit is not 1.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Where is the source of this puzzle? Please note that questions from other places **must** be credited correctly (and make sure you have permission to use them!)

Comment: Hello there,the puzzle is made by me so i am the source(?),my inspiration started after starting computer science logic.

Comment: May I suggest using the letters A,B and C instead of numbers for the code, that would make them a lot easier to distinguish from the ubiquitous "Nth digit" numbers.

Comment: I think real answer is: **Any place**!! ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing we can say for sure is that

> the $3^{rd}$ digit is a $2$. The other positions can be anything.

Proof:

> If the $1^{st}$ digit is a $3$ then we are done.
>
>  If not, then digit:$2$ is a $3$. Now assume digit:$3$ is not a $2$, therefore digit:$4$ is a $2$ (by (4)), and so digit:$5$ is a $1$ (by (3)).
>
>  However (5) tells us that if digit:$2$=3 and digit:$4$=2, then digit:$5$ is not $1$, which is a contradiction, so digit:$3$=2.
>
>  For the other digit positions, these codes, $13231,23213,31211,32222$, contain a $1$, $2$ or $3$ in every other position.

Using some JavaScript:

> ```
>  s=[]; 
>  for (a=1;a<4;a++)
>  for (b=1;b<4;b++)
>  for (c=1;c<4;c++)
>  for (d=1;d<4;d++)
>  for (e=1;e<4;e++) {
>  if (a!=3 && b!=3) continue;
>  if (a==3 && c!=2) continue;
>  if (b==3 && d==2 && e!=1) continue;
>  if (c!=2 && d!=2) continue;
>  if (c!=2 && e==1) continue;
>  s.push(''+a+b+c+d+e);
>  }
>  console.log(s);
> ```

we get:

> $13211,13212,13213,13221,13231,\\13232,13233,23211,23212,23213,\\ 23221,23231,23232,23233,31211,\\31212,31213,31221,31222,31223,\\ 31231,31232,31233,32211,32212,\\32213,32221,32222,32223,32231,\\ 32232,32233,33211,33212,33213,\\33221,33231,33232,33233$
>
>  which is $39$ codes in total.

Comment: You mean rot13("vs gur svefg qvtvg vf guerr") at the start of the proof? May I also suggest putting the proof first, then picking two examples to show rot13(gjb pna nyfb tb va nal bgure cbfvgvba), then the program as a postscript.

Answer (score 2):

Using the corrected program by @JonMarkPerry,

> i.e. by changing  if (c!=3 && d!=2) continue; to  if (c!=2 && d!=2) continue;

We get

> 13211, 13212, 13213, 13221, 13231, 13232, 13233, 23211, 23212, 23213, 23221, 23231, 23232, 23233, 31211, 31212, 31213, 31221, 31222, 31223, 31231, 31232, 31233, 32211, 32212, 32213, 32221, 32222, 32223, 32231, 32232, 32233, 33211, 33212, 33213, 33221, 33231, 33232, 33233

Which means

> the third position is always 2, and others may be also.